# How to use Markov's to prove a limit?

Tags: probability

[image]

I am stuck on parts c and e.

For the first parts I get $1/n^2$ and $1/n$ respectively.

For c I used Markov's to get $E[Y] =\frac{1}{n}\geq tP(Y \geq t) \geq0$ and obviously $1/n$ goes to $0$ so $tP(Y \geq t)$ goes to $0$ for arbitrary $t$ but how would I know $P(Y \geq t)$ goes to $0$ on its own as $n$ goes to $\infty$?

Then for the last two parts for d I'm pretty sure this is trivial by c since if $Y>0 \iff \exists X_i>2ln(n)$  so if one probability goes to $0$ the other does as well.

But for e I don't see where I used it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $Y$ is an integer, we have
$$
\Pr[Y > 0] = \Pr[Y \geq 1] \leq \frac{\mathsf{E}[Y]}{1} = \frac{1}{n}
$$
thus (c) holds.

For (e), I agree that the condition of independence is not used.

Comment: Okay I get it now thanks. I didn't notice to switch to $\geq 1$.